# Tunnel a ssh tunnel through a unix socket and connect to it using ssh

Tags: ssh, tunnel, sockets

Ok, the title might be a bit confusing so here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I have multiple machines of types A that would connect to a server B. All machines of type A would have some kind of GUID.

What I'm trying to achieve is that machine A would initiate a SSH tunnel to server B then someone from his personal computer can connect to machines of type A through server B.

I'm able to port forward it like this:

```
ssh -R 3000:localhost:22 server_host -p 58122
```

But that's not really convenient as I'd have to guess an unused port.

I'd rather have something like this:

```
ssh -R /tmp/nodes/${guid}.sock:localhost:22 server_host -p 58122
```

Then something like this from the server B:

```
ssh /tmp/nodes/${guid}.sock
```

But the first command always return this:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen path /tmp/guid.sock
```

As if the socket couldn't be created. The ssh client connect to the server B but cannot initiate a socket for its own ssh port.

The main goal is to be able to create a SSH tunnel from the node machines A to the server B. The reason is that those machines are hidden behind a network and there is no real other way to create a tunnel from Server B to nodes A.

I'm not even sure ssh can connect directly to a socket so if there is an alternative to port forwarding I'd be happy to know.

Comment: A VPN may be the wheel you're trying to reinvent.

Comment: Note: you got `remote port forwarding failed` probably because there is `/tmp/guid.sock` on B from your previous try. The fact a socket gets left behind will complicate your procedure. Connecting to a valid socket [is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451791/108618).

Comment: The socket was never created so no, I think the problem is in a configuration. I ended up with something working on 2 of my machine locally.

Comment: As for the VPN, it may be a solution but we'd have to create a VPN for each client and have a way to configure the VPNs remotely, that said it kind of simplify how to ssh the nodes.

Comment: "to create a VPN for each client" -- Why? Before you answer, read [this](https://serverfault.com/a/570320).

Comment: Oh so by default vpn clients can't see each other? Then that's probably a better solution than messing with ssh tunnels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83315/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-loic-faure-lacroix).

Comment: well I haven't fully grasped / studied what you're saying, but if you can do multiple with things like -L .....-L .....-L ...... multiple times, or -R ....-R ....-R ......multiple times.

Answer (score -2):

You could try and use ssh tunnel and socat.

https://gist.github.com/ljjjustin/585e817d1d7ce4eb75b87076e5b7aa7e

Here is a script to inspire you.

Comment: That answer would benefit from more details instead of a link for inspiration.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.